# Problem with nvidia-persistenced not working

Tags: nvidia

I'm having a problem which I think I've narrowed down to the nvidia persistence daemon.

Issue:  I have my HTPC connected to my Onkyo receiver.  When I turn off the receiver and turn it back on, I have no signal from the HTPC.  I can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> and run `sudo stop lightdm` then `sudo start lightdm`.  Once I do this I'm back to the regular screen.  This is not a long-term solution though as

1. it's a pain
2. I will have other users who want to watch TV and will not know what to do.

Through my googlefu I found that I need to set persistence-mode to on, though this will be going away.  I have tried this method with `sudo "nvidia-smi -pm 1"` and it will set it to on, but it doesn't appear to work as the issue will re-occur.

I have also tried running `sudo nvidia-persistenced --user [user] --persistence-mode` and I can see a process start. When I turn my receiver off though, the same thing occurs.

The `syslog` has the following:

```
... nvidia-persistenced: Failed to open PID file: File exists
... nvidia-persistenced: Shutdown (5232)
```

I have made sure the user I have `nvidia-persistenced` running as is part of the `nvidia-persistenced` group.  I have also set permissions on the `/var/run/nvidia-persistenced/` folder to 777.

I'm going crazy trying to resolve this.  I want to be able to turn my receiver off and when I turn it back on have the screen where I left off.

- Running Ubuntu 14.04 (Mythbuntu install)
- Video card is Nvidia GT 730 using driver 352.63

Also, once I get the `nvidia-persistenced` daemon working, I need to set it up to start at system startup.  How would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 7):

**May 2019**

With regards to the errors:

```
... nvidia-persistenced: Failed to open PID file: File exists
... nvidia-persistenced: Shutdown (5232)
```

I got this error on Ubuntu 18.04.02 LTS after installation of the CUDA toolkit (10.0) and trying to follow the recommended post installation actions. I followed the guide to install via the nvidia repository.

https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html#install-persistenced

The issue for me was that the daemon was actually running already.

To verify run:

```
ps aux | grep persistenced
```

and you should get something along the lines

```
root       714  0.0  0.0   8864  1396 ?        Ss   19:44   0:00 /usr/bin/nvidia-persistenced --verbose
root      6723  0.0  0.0  22000  1112 pts/0    S+   20:25   0:00 grep --color=auto persistenced
```

Process 714 (in your case the pid will likely be different) is the daemon already running which is why when I executed the command again it failed.

So the service was actually installed already by the cuda packages.
To confirm this run:

```
systemctl list-units --type service --all | grep nvidia
```

and you should get something like the following:

```
  nvidia-persistenced.service                           loaded    active   running NVIDIA Persistence Daemon
```

This confirms the service is already up and running.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to resolve this issue with assistance from another forum, but here is the resolution in-case anyone is interested.

Basically follow the instructions in this link: https://www.mythtv.org/wiki/Nvidia-cards_and_no_picture_when_box_is_on_before_the_TV

In case that link is removed, here's the gist of what I did:

- Run 'nvidia-settings' on the local X-Server
- Click the entry corresponding to your TV (e.g. DFP-0) Click 'Acquire
- EDID' and save the 'edid.bin' file someplace safe, for instance
  '/etc/X11/tv-edid.bin'
- Open your existing config file, usually in /etc/X11/xorg.conf
- Find the 'Device' section for your video card.
- Add a line to force the stored EDID:
- `Option "CustomEDID" "DFP-0:/etc/X11/edid.bin"`
- Reboot

I ended up adding the following lines as well, not sure if they are needed or not though:

```
Option "ModeValidation" "NoDFPNativeResolutionCheck"
Option "ExactModeTimingsDVI" "True"
Option "UseDisplayDevice" "DFP-0"
Option "ConnectedMonitor" "DFP-0" `
```

Now I'm able to turn off my receiver and/or change the inputs and I can return to my HTPC exactly where I left off.

Answer (score 1):

Try to install libcupti, it helped me.

```
sudo apt-get install libcupti-dev
```

I dont know why this is helping. But this one of the libs that Tensorflow [asks for during installation](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_linux). Specifically, it is listed under "NVIDIA requirements to run TensorFlow with GPU support":

> The libcupti-dev library, which is the NVIDIA CUDA Profile Tools Interface. This library provides advanced profiling support.

Also there can be problem with kernels, which i found, fixed here: [Nvidia drivers failed & login loop proplems](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1022189/nvidia-drivers-failed-login-loop-proplems/1022190#1022190)

Comment: Can you **[edit]** this with some information about why that might help?

Comment: @EliahKagan i dont know why this is helping. But this one of the libs that Tensorflow asking during install https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_linux