# Nvidia drivers failed & login loop proplems

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, xorg, cuda

So few days ago i tried to update my Nvidia drivers from 384 to 390. After update drivers not worked.

Kernel logs showed me this error:

```
nvidia: version magic '4.4.0-119-generic SMP mod_unload modversions ' should be '4.4.0-119-generic SMP mod_unload modversions retpoline '
```

Xorg logs showed this:

```
[   407.015] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic" does not exist.
[   407.015] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/" does not exist.
[   407.015] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/" does not exist.
[   407.015] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi" does not exist.
[   407.015] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi" does not exist.
[   407.023] (WW) "glamoregl" will not be loaded unless you've specified it to be loaded elsewhere.
```

`modprobe nvidia` did't find needed module:

```
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'nvidia': No such device
```

But card was found by system:

```
lspci | grep NVIDIA
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM107M [GeForce GTX 960M] (rev a2)
```

**Kernel** 4.4.0-119-generic
**System:** Ubuntu 16.04

How to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after one day i found solution to this problem. The main fail was in gcc compiler which was installed from test repository(I need it for golang), but which brakes kernel.

So what i did to fix this:

1. Login to tty1 with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F1</kbd> on
   login Screen.
2. Stop lightdm servie with `sudo service lightdm stop`
3. Purge all nvidia and cuda packages with 'sudo apt purge nvidia-*
   cuda-*'
4. Install purge ppa tool: `sudo apt-get install ppa-purge`
5. Remove test ppa: `sudo ppa-purge ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test`
6. Check gcc version, now it should be 5.4.0. `gcc --version`
7. Remove old kernels: `sudo apt-get purge linux-headers-4.4.0-119 linux-headers-4.4.0-119-generic linux-image-4.4.0-119-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-119-generic linux-signed-image-4.4.0-119-generic`
8. Reinstall kernel: `sudo apt-get install linux-generic linux-signed-generic`
9. Reboot `sudo reboot` (after reboot you may see black screen, it's ok)
10. Repeat 1-2
11. Install nvidia drivers

`wget http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1604/x86_64/cuda-repo-ubuntu1604_9.1.85-1_amd64.deb`

`sudo dpkg -i cuda-repo-ubuntu1604_9.1.85-1_amd64.deb`

`sudo apt-key adv --fetch-keys http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1604/x86_64/7fa2af80.pub`

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt install nvidia-390 nvidia-390-dev`

12. Reinstall ubuntu-desktop `sudo apt install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop`
13. Reboot
14. Profit!